# Temporary file BASH

Tags: bash

does this piece of code creates temporary file? Because I am not supposed to use them and I only found out yesterday that even sed -i creates it. So I can be sure. Thanks

```
while read line; do
if [[ $line =~ "$PWD"$ ]] ;then 
IFS=" " read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 <<<"$line"
fi
done <file.txt
```

Comment: No, not a real file on the filesystem.

Comment: If this is for coursework, are you sure that your restriction on temporary files applies to the implementation detail within `bash` itself? I would have thought probably not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, bash **will** create a temporary file with *here-documents* and with *here-strings*; you used the latter in your script.

(You can test this by inspecting the `/tmp` directory while a test program with a `sleep` delay is running.)

Comment: Oh, that sucks :( So is there any way to avoid it? But I'm guessing not.

Comment: Possibly many ways to avoid that; but that depends on your data and intention. At first glance the PWD test may be implemented differently, then you could split the fields already in the `while read` loop, by providing five arguments to read instead of one. (If we knew about the syntax of your data file we could possibly provide more specific hints.)

Comment: so read -r itself doesnt create anything temporary?

Comment: and I tried to look in /tmp directory, but it didnt create anything.

Comment: Start a test program that contains code like `while read line; do sleep 10; done <<< "abc"` and run in the background by terminating with a `&`. Then within the 10 seconds inspect the `/tmp` directory. (Depending on your system and settings the directory for temporary files may be located elsewhere than directly under the root `/`, though.)